# WPA2 Wi-Fi connecting but not working on MacBook Pro 4.1

Tags: wireless, 13.10, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 4.1 with Ubuntu 13.10 installed, as well as the Broadcom drivers installed (in Software & Updates/Additional Drivers)

Connecting to an unsecured network or WEP seems to work, but there is one that is WPA2 that I can connect to but once I am connected I am not able to ping anything including local machines or go out to the Internet. OS X machines and android devices have been able to successfully connect to this network.

Output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
```

Nm-tool: http://pastebin.com/Mq6B3XJZ

Note that Work Guest is the one I have succesfully connected to. WORK SUPPPORT is the one I am having issues with

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about your device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with the output

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try a newer version of the Broadcom STA driver. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do for a 32-bit system:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/src/hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-6.30.223.141
wget http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/36/49/2865859-hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v6_30_223_141_dkms.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf 2865859-hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v6_30_223_141_dkms.tar.gz -C /usr/src/hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-6.30.223.141
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo dkms add -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_32 -v 6.30.223.141
sudo dkms build -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_32 -v 6.30.223.141
sudo dkms install -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_32 -v 6.30.223.141
```

For a 64-bit system:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/src/hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-6.30.223.141
wget http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/36/49/2865859-hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v6_30_223_141_dkms.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf 2865859-hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v6_30_223_141_dkms.tar.gz -C /usr/src/hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-6.30.223.141 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo dkms add -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_64 -v 6.30.223.141
sudo dkms build -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_64 -v 6.30.223.141
sudo dkms install -m hybrid-portsrc_x86_64 -v 6.30.223.141
```

Then, in both cases, do:

```
echo -e "blacklist b43\nblacklist bcma\nblacklist brcmsmac\nblacklist ssb" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_Broadcom.conf
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

If you get 'bad return status' check the log referred to:

```
less /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.1_dkms/build/make.log
```

Report the error for our examination.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will give this a shot soon, need to finish some stuff up before having the chance to reboot

Comment: Tried this and when I got to the build nnd install commands at the end I get this error: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-15-generic (x86_64)

Comment: Please see my edit.